# jQuery "unobtrusive" ajax causes massive warnings explosion

Tags: jquery, ajax, razor

Every click event fires off about 4 to 8 warnings depending on how hard you try. It adds up to a hundred plus pretty easy. The warning reads `event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future.` The warnings are a result of including this in my view (this is in an asp.net mvc3 view)

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

What gives, why all the warnings?

Comment: Weird way to do a script source.. Why is it strange like that?

Comment: @DanRedux - That markup is from the razor engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try comparing the to the jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js from MVC4 and/or use Microsoft's CDN.  http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx#ASPNET_MVC_Releases_on_the_CDN_10

Comment: I believe that these warnings are actually a bug with chrome coupled with an improper implementation in part of webkit. I am using jQuery 1.4.4 and I read that it is fixed in the new 1.7. I suppose I will just have to live with the warnings.

Comment: Or upgrade to jQuery 1.7.2, jQuery Validate 1.9 http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx#jQuery_Validation_Releases_on_the_CDN_2 and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: @robich - I would, but I have a lot of jQuery in different spots. Changing the 1.7.2 in one spot would break all those spots that use `live` and `attr` and then I would have to hunt each one down. For now, this system is just going to have to limp on with 1.4.4